# Why does my computer turn itself off?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, event-log

I have an old laptop with Windows 7 system, and I want to use it as a home server. I put it under a desk, and control it via Remote Desktop Connection on a MacBook Pro. Both the laptop and the macbook are connected to my home router.

It works almost well, except the laptop is keeping turning itself off. About 3 times in a week. On mourning, when I wanted to connect to the laptop, I found it was down.I checked the event log on the Windows 7, and I found it was off almost the same time I turned off my macbook and went to sleep. I don't know why and how to fix it. Can anyone help me figure out what cause the problem?

Comment: Look under the power settings and disable the shutdown after some time of inactivity. Also look in the eventlog for details why Windows did the shutdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of these parameters can be your problem:

- Power Option Setting in the control panel.
- Hardware problem (CPU Fan, Battery, Laptop Power Board, ...).
- Other software which you installed.

you can install Ubuntu or other Linux and check your laptop, If turn it off again your hardware has a problem. With CPU-z and GPU-z application you can check your hardware temperature and other detail.

Comment: Is there any log file I can check out why it is shutting down?

Comment: it was hibernating. I turned the function off, and now it is ok. Thanks.